# Time Complexity of my 2 pointer algorithm

Tags: javascript, code-complexity

For the given problem below, what would be the time complexity of my solution (below the problem). I think it is not O(n^2), but I am not sure if it is O(n).

Problem: You are given two strings s and t. You can select any substring of string s and rearrange the characters of the selected substring. Determine the minimum length of the substring of s such that string t is a substring of the selected substring.

Signature int minLengthSubstring(String s, String t)

Input s and t are non-empty strings that contain less than 1,000,000 characters each

Output Return the minimum length of the substring of s. If it is not possible, return -1

Example s = "dcbefebce" t = "fd" output = 5

Explanation: Substring "dcbef" can be rearranged to "cfdeb", "cefdb", and so on. String t is a substring of "cfdeb". Thus, the minimum length required is 5.

My code:

```
function minLengthSubstring(s, t) {
  // Write your code here
  if(t.length > s.length) return -1;
  
  let letters = new Map();
  for(const tc of t) {
    letters.set(tc, (letters.get(t) || 0) +1);
  }
  
  let min = Infinity;
  let start = 0;
  let i = 0;
  let count = 0;
  let map = new Map(letters);
  while(i < s.length) {
    if(map.has(s[i])) {
      if(start === 0 && count === 0)  start = i;
      count++;
      if(map.get(s[i]) === 1) map.delete(s[i])
      else  map.set(s[i], map.get(s[i]) -1);
      if(count === t.length) {
        min = Math.min(min, i-start+1);
        map = new Map(letters);
        count = 0;
        start++;
        i = start;
      }
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  return min === Infinity ? -1 : min;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Its not n^2 its 2n and in big o notation : `O(|k|*n) = O(n)` so its O(n).

Comment: @Eldar Thank you. Could you please explain why it's O(n)? Inside the while loop and recreating the Map of letters, isn't it another loop?

Comment: Well actually didn't notice that you are initializing a `Map` there. Since its implementation detail is not clear enough (a container selected based on the situation. You can check [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/refs/heads/main/containers)) (It could either copy a  memory block, O(1) constructed from another map or it could be O(n) or worse ).  IMO implementation detail should be out of the big O calculation. Also, you can try with just an object instead of a map and see the difference. In the end you have 2 loops which brings : O(2*n) = O(n)

Comment: @Eldar Got it. Thank you. If you want to respond the question, I can accept it as answer.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help.